# What kind of damage can a single swing of a super sharp sword at super speed do?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, magic, weapons

The wielder is super-human, enhanced by magic, able to swing the sword at any speed physically possible (without breaking the laws of physics). The sword is ultra-sharp, with an edge of any sharpness (a single molecule wide or dull), and won't break because of magic. For now, only the wielder and the sword should be magically enhanced. Every else should follow the laws of physics.

Cutting the target is a given, but I'm looking for some extra damage. A first thought of mine is sonic booms. I'm not sure how that may add to the damage though. I'm also not sure if there are speeds so fast that they lose some special damage effects.

Given such a weapon and wielder, what kind of damage can a single swing possibly do?

Comment: Most likely what you'd expect: slash through most materials. Unless this thing is trailing at extremely high speeds, it won't do much more. At high enough speeds your wielder might have to worry about causing the nearby air to turn into plasma by swinging the arm, as well as a loud sonic boom.

Comment: Pretty sure anything indestructible going sufficiently fast will vaporize everything in it's path, possibly breaking it down to plasma, and if fast enough, subatomic particles. Maybe cause a nuclear explosion? No matter what, BOOM.

Comment: Once the super-human has sliced the orc in half with her mighty first stroke, I'm not sure what additional damage is really needed. Um, remember to have the intrepid hero wear hearing protection, or all those close sonic booms will damage her super-hearing.

Comment: Just assume the target of the cutting isn't quite destroyed with just cutting. May be it can regenerate or cut damage is mostly ineffective and some explosiveness is needed. I'd like details on how the sword can do additional damage with the plasma, vaporization, sonic booms, etc.

Comment: Is the wielder human-shaped and sized?  As @Halfthawed noted in answer, the monomolecular sword blade is too thin to interact with the air significantly, but the arm wielding the sword potentially will be devastating...  Also note that if cutting isn't the best way to destroy the enemy, a monomolecular sword is the worst possible choice of weapon!

Comment: You might not want to make the sword as sharp as possible, rather have a dull edge instead. If you can swing it at enough speed to cause sonic booms or plasma, chances are you're going through your target either way. If the sword shattering is no issue, you might as well take a good chunk out of your opponent, to make the cut harder to heal/regenerate. Generally the rule is the cleaner the cut, the easier it is to heal. A shredded/serrated wound would be much more preferable.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of damaging effects the sword can have as it goes super-speed. At supersonic speeds, sonic booms may happen. There may be a speed at which sonic booms won't happen, but something else. I'm thinking about what kind of extra damage I can get from each speed range.

Answer (score 1):

**It's really dangerous until it goes fast enough to get really awesome**

For starters, the 'monomolecular edge' isn't helpful at all to actually being an effective sword, it's actually the opposite. Force is just 1/2 mass * velocity, so a mono-molecular blade, which has really little mass, will just have really little force, so once you get past a certain point it really makes no difference just *how* fast you swing because there's so little force behind it and all that force is getting transferred to air which doesn't conduct well at all. Anyway, there are three main outcomes, aside from 'cutting things well'

1 - The Blade Shatters: If the sword is weaker than whatever you're swinging it at, the sword will break. The molecule-thin edge doesn't matter. You swing a molecular blade made of warm butter at a block of metal, it's not the metal that's breaking. Similarly, you swing a length of razor-thin tool steel at a titanium door, the blade is going to shatter.

2 - The Blade Shatters, Except Into Shrapnel: The reason it took humans so long to break the sound barrier is that they kept dying when the plane hit the sonic boom. Why do I bring this up? Well, if you swing the sword fast enough ('fast enough' here is relative to the material the sword is made out of) then the sword will shatter from the shockwave it generates, and given the molecular nature of the sword and the likely speed it was going (i.e. possibly supersonic) then you will have monomolecular shrapnel flying everywhere. It may not kill you. But it will hurt.

3 - The Blade Cuts The Air Into Plasma: So, assuming you managed to skip the 'sonic-boom-into-shrapnel' step by magically making the sword unbreakable, you still have a problem once you start exceed certain speeds (i.e. appreciable fractions of the speed of light) because then the sword start smashing the air molecules into plasma. Now, funnily enough, I'm not sure this will kill you - air isn't dense at all and a molecular sword edge will only turn air molecules into plasma when it makes the air hit each other. (Its not going to cut the air molecules in half.) So it's going to have a very thin veneer of a plasma trail following it as it cuts a molecular-thin line of plasma through the air, which will look *amazing*, but somehow not be dangerous at all because it's only a molecule-thick.

That said, swinging it faster, at least past a certain speed won't make it any more dangerous towards whatever you're swinging it at - it'll cut just as well.

Comment: To avoid the blade shattering problem, I've made the blade magically enhanced to be unbreakable. The edge can be any thickness, but I just thought making it as sharp as possible may be fun.

Comment: @John Zhau  - The problem with this is that you, John Zhau, can magic the sword to do anything you want it to. We can't tell you what your magic will achieve, only you know this.

Comment: The only thing affected by magic is that the wielder has super-human speed and strength and the sword is unbreakable. Everything else should follow the laws of physics. Once I've got the "extra damage" ideas, I can then use magic/science to enhance that extra effect,

Comment: @JohnZhau If you're using magic strength and speed, you're better off using a hammer than a sword.

Comment: My character is a master swordsman. The only weapong he's using here is his sword.